# Is the FileOutputFormat.setCompressOutput(job, true); optional?

Tags: hadoop, compression

In Hadoop program, I tried to compress the result, I wrote the following code:

```
FileOutputFormat.setCompressOutput(job, true); 
FileOutputFormat.setOutputCompressorClass(job, GzipCodec.class);
```

The result was compressed, and when I delete the first line:

```
FileOutputFormat.setCompressOutput(job, true);
```

and execute the program again, the result was same, was the above code

> FileOutputFormat.setCompressOutput(job, true);

optional? What is the function of that code?

Comment: please check my answer. hope this is useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the below methods in [FileOutPutFormat.java](https://github.com/facebookarchive/hadoop-20/blob/master/src/mapred/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileOutputFormat.java) which internally calls the method call which you have deleted.

> i.e  setCompressOutput(conf, true);

That means you are trying apply Gzip codec class then obviously its a pointer to code that output should be compressed. Isnt it ?

```
/**
   * Set whether the output of the job is compressed.
   * @param conf the {@link JobConf} to modify
   * @param compress should the output of the job be compressed?
   */
  public static void setCompressOutput(JobConf conf, boolean compress) {
    conf.setBoolean("mapred.output.compress", compress);
  }
  /**
   * Set the {@link CompressionCodec} to be used to compress job outputs.
   * @param conf the {@link JobConf} to modify
   * @param codecClass the {@link CompressionCodec} to be used to
   *                   compress the job outputs
   */
  public static void 
  setOutputCompressorClass(JobConf conf, 
                           Class<? extends CompressionCodec> codecClass) {
    setCompressOutput(conf, true);
    conf.setClass("mapred.output.compression.codec", codecClass, 
                  CompressionCodec.class);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have another question now. Please see my question again.

Comment: Ideally new question should be posted... however, Hadoop 2.4.1 which is 
 older version of HADOOP has this issue by setting native lib as false and forcing map output to be compressed. For More detail you can see here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-11334

Comment: Hi I think my problem is different from the link you  quoted.My warn is :  WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local1149103367_0001

Comment: As per the stack trace, it looks like you are running the Job in local mode. Do you see the issue when you run the same job in YARN mode(i.e. mapreduce.framework.name=yarn) as well?

Comment: Also, make sure Gzip compression lib were installed properly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113123/discussion-between-coinnigh-and-ramprasad-g).